# New users golfing code

Tags: discussion, editing, new-users

The last two Suggested Edit reviews I have reviewed, they were easy rejects. Both were from a new user ([the same](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56941/chromozorz)), and both were golfing/"fixing" the code. I admit to have done this before, but a while ago. I therefore propose that there should be a new box when editing a post.

Instead of

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

I suggest there should be a last line:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary. **Do not** edit the code unless this is Community Wiki, please `[comment](link-to-comment)`.

Comment: Not sure if this can be adjusted just for PPCG. Also, this particular user doesn't have enough rep to post comments.

Comment: @Dennis I know. Even if they can't comment, they shouldn't make an edit like that.

Comment: I'm not saying edits like those should be suggested, but asking the user to comment instead when he can't is a bit weird. Maybe *Once you earn 50 reputation, you'll be able to [comment everywhere](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).* would be better.

Comment: Might be worth adding this to [this thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8350/8478) which I'm told is currently being reviewed by the CMs.

Comment: @Dennis The 50 rep commenting system is there for a reason; comments-in-posts are an easy reject (or accept and edit).

Comment: Your edit should not be an edit but a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I think that would be a good idea. New users cannot comment on submissions and editing may seem like the obvious solution so a clear statement advising otherwise seems appropriate. If edits aren't allowed then why not get rid of that functionality?

Personally however, I find it more harmful for users to be submitting incorrect submissions, getting votes for them and potentially winning the challenge than for a user to make an edit to the submission. Otherwise what is the point of PPCG? I can submit 'f' as my answer and I can win... Doesn't seem right.

Comment: How should I approach that situation then (I didn't edit his code, I pasted a note below in the edit)? If it's just going to be left as in then I can literally type some bullshit and it will win.

Comment: `I can submit 'f' as my answer and I can win... Doesn't seem right.` Actually, you couldn't. High-rep users and moderators can delete invalid answers. Low-rep users can downvote and flag. The challenge poster can choose not to accept it. Generally this community gets rid of invalid posts pretty quickly.

Comment: I feel like you are trying to bash a [specific answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85568/45941), which really isn't nice.

Comment: I hadn't seen that. Of course I am not. If it's a part of the language then I have no issue with that! 
At least I can reproduce and confirm that answer. The question I am referring to had code that I pasted in my console and it spat out a result that was different to what he had written. What's more likely; the language just decided to give the wrong result or the user submitted incorrect code?

Bear in mind that not many people use the language here so it may be easier to get away with incorrect submissions. If I am one of the few that use it then I see it as a duty to highlight it.

Comment: I am not saying it is not harmful, just now you can comment.

Comment: @Chromozorz Simply comment that you tried the code and got a different result. He may have a different version of the language, or it may have been a mistake the user didn't catch. An edit is not warranted.

Comment: @mbomb007 I agree that's an appropriate route to take HOWEVER new users cannot comment! Telling a new user not to edit but rather comment when they CANNOT comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Chromozorz Sure it does. It simply means that they don't do that until they've received enough reputation. As Dennis said, we can use a message like "Once you earn 50 reputation, you'll be able to comment everywhere." They still need to know that it should be a comment for when they *are* able to. They just need to ask a question or answer one to earn the necessary rep first.